# Scheduling events in linux

Tags: linux, scheduling

My requirement is for some kind of scheduler, where i can register a callback with it and tell the scheduler to invoke the callback after a specified time period. This needs to be done via an API and the number of callbacks that are registered with the scheduler can vary from few hundred to few thousands a second (under 10k a sec). The average time period specified per callback is around 5 minutes. 
    I was  wondering if Linux has some utility that can provide me above services or would i need to build something from scratch. Any reference to similar projects would be helpful.

Comment: which language are you using? C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard, old fashioned C/Unix way of doing this would be to use "TIMER" and a SIGALRM signal handler:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=356101

Comment: Would you know if it would scale to the above frequency from few hundreds to about 10k a sec?

Answer (score 1):

Got a signalling-free non-blocking scheduler prototype at [sf.net/projects/ksched](http://sf.net/projects/ksched) > Code > git. (Your post gave an incentive to start working on this again.)

Answer (score 0):

Linux, being a Unix, has cron.  But your concept of "callback" would be run some bash script or program.  I don't know exactly how you would "push" values into it via API, but I suspect you could do it through system calls.  It seems kind of long winded to me, though.  Get yourself a Java compiler and check out the Quartz library.  Quartz is cron in Java.  It has a full on API that your Java program can interact with.